# Music settings for a specific app,How to do this?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I am using AudioManager but when i turn off the sound it turn off the whole system sound,if there any way to turn off sound to a specific app only.

I have tried this code

```
if (VolIsMute) {
    manager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
    VolIsMute = false;
} else {
    manager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
    VolIsMute = true;
}
```

Comment: Tell me if I understood this correctly, you want your app to manage the audio settings of all other apps in the system? Or you just want your app to have specific audio settings?

Comment: just want my app to have specific audio settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very simple solution for it

Here is my code

```
Switch aSwitch;
Button buttonPlay;
int flag;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    aSwitch = findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    buttonPlay = findViewById(R.id.button);

    final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sample);

    aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                flag = 1;
            }else{
               flag = 0;
            }
        }
    });
    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (flag == 0){
                mp1.start();
            }
        }
    });
```